# pod dependent on another pod how to specify path in the podspec

Tags: swift4, xcode9

I have created a framework which I am integrating into an app via cocoapods. I need to add a functionality to it which is dependent on another pod. The pod which is needed for my framework to function is not open source. Is there a possibility of specifying the path in the podspec?

Comment: can you give more details on this problem like your pod file content

Comment: The main app has a Podfile which contains the path to the pod I developed. In the framework I have added a podspec which has it's specifications. This pod is now to supposed to be dependent on another pod which is in a private repo. If the dependency would have open source then s.dependency would have worked. Is there a way I could mention the path of the private repo in my podspec